# Can someone explain the DOM situation when I'm submitting a form?

Tags: jquery, html

Not sure exactly how to ask this question, it's regarding terminology of the DOM and how it works. But basically, I've been trying to just submit forms and grab the value on the same page using pure client code.

So I ended up having some handler function:

```
<form onsubmit="readInput(this);">   ...</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function readInput(form){...} 
</script>
```

Inside the readInput function, I have form.elements[0].value which gives me the actual value of one of the inputs I submitted. document.getElementBy... also works the same in grabbing that value. But jQuery selectors will not grab that attribute.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm really bad at phrasing. and my question is just the title itself. Since I'm unclear on the concept, I'm not sure exactly how to phrase the question. So here goes again.

The situation described above where I try to grab all the values (using document.getElementBy..., using form.elements[0],  and the selector) is when I set a breakpoint inside the readInput function. I'm just wondering why document.getElementByID gives me a value and is considered grabbing an element from the DOM but at that point in the code, the change inside the "DOM" when I inspect the element does not hold the actual value. Are the elements in "Inspect the Element" not necessarily containing the full contents of the DOM?

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: Check out `jQuery('form').serialize();`

Comment: DOM stands for Document _Object_ Model, you are dealing with object's properties not attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> jQuery selector didn't grab that form value

We can't tell why code you aren't sharing with us doesn't work, but I'd hazard a guess that you are using `attr('value')` instead of `val()` to read the value once you have selected it.

> when I "inspect element -> elements category," the value is clearly empty, does that mean the DOM is not updated?

No. It means that the `value` **attribute** reflects the *initial* value not the *current* value (which is exposed through the `value` **property**).

[image]